# Find $F''(x)$ knowing that $F(x)=\int_0^x\left ( \int_1^{\sin(t)}\sqrt{1+u^4} \, du\right)dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I'm clueless on this one :'( can you guys please show me the general way to solve this kind of problems?

> Find $F''(x)$ knowing that:
>   $$F(x)=\int_0^x\left ( \int_1^{\sin t}\sqrt{1+u^4} \, du\right)dt$$

Comment: Fundamental theorem of calculus says if $f(x) = \int_{a}^{u(x)} g(t)\ dt$ then $f'(x) = g(u(x)) u'(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a lovely FTC problem, isn't it?

For the first derivative, we can just extract the function from inside the $dt$ integral, replacing $t$ with $x$. Thus:

$$F'(x)=\int_1^{\sin x}\sqrt{1+u^4}\,du$$

Now, to differentiate again, we need to use the chain rule, where the outside function is the one defined by the integral, and the inside function is $\sin x$. Thus:

$$\begin{align}F''(x) &= \sqrt{1+\sin^4 x}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}[\sin x]\\
&=\sqrt{1+\sin^4 x}\cdot\cos x
\end{align}$$

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks! So, I was close with my first though, I was missing the chain rule :'D

Answer (score 3):

If $\displaystyle F(x) = \int_0^x \Big(\text{some function of }t\Big) \, dt$ then $F'(x) = \text{that same function evalutate at }x.$ That gets you the first derivative. For the second derivative, do the same thing, except that you also need that chain rule since you have $\sin t$ rather than just $t.$